# Boot hang: systemd-journald Failed to send stream file descriptor to service manager: connection refused

Tags: boot-repair

I'm stuck at boot with this screen. How can I fix this?

[image: boot screen]

Comment: This happens to me every so often (maybe 1/8 times?) on Ubuntu 18.04. I hit reset, and the next boot works fine. Have you learned anything new about it since your post 6 months ago?

Comment: 2 years on ... anybody?